# Add Check Boxes to a userform with multiple sections that will input a number located on Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am new to VBA, and I am working on a userform, which was created by someone else. The userform has four areas(Cost Code1, Cost Code 2, exc...) that input information(Cost Code, Truck Rent, Regular Hours and Overtime Hours) into specific columns on the worksheet. Right now there are text boxes at the top of the form that enters the employee name, job number and date with all of the information.

The new project has two job numbers, so instead of using the Job Number Text Box at the top, I need to add Option Buttons, or Check Boxes (whichever is easier) to choose between the two different job numbers for the four groups of information. I would like to only be allowed to select one job number per area on the userform. The job numbers will be located on a second tab called Employees in cells H1 and K1.  I need the job number to be entered in column number 4.  What is the code for the Check Boxes, or Option Buttons, and where would I enter it in the original code?  I appreciate any help.

```
Private Sub cbOK_Click()
Dim NextRow As Long
'Variable for cycling through cell input
Dim i As Long
Dim Userdate As Date
i = 1

Set EESheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Employees")
Set TLISheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet")

'Activate Worksheet Tab
Sheets("Worksheet").Activate
'Set Autocalc off to speed things up.
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


'Error Handling, go to bad.
On Error GoTo Bad



Userdate = tbDate.Value
'Transfer the data to the rows
For i = 1 To 6
    NextRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
        If Me.Controls("tbCC" & i & "RegHrs").Value <> "" Then
            Cells(NextRow, 1) = tbDate.Value
            Cells(NextRow, 2) = cmbEmployeeName.Value
            Cells(NextRow, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cmbEmployeeName.Value, EESheet.Range("A:B"), 2, False)
            Cells(NextRow, 4) = tbJobNumber.Value
            Cells(NextRow, 5) = Me.Controls("tbJobExtra" & i).Value
            Cells(NextRow, 6) = Me.Controls("cmbCC" & i).Value
            Cells(NextRow, 7) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cmbEmployeeName.Value, EESheet.Range("A:C"), 3, False)
            Cells(NextRow, 8) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cmbEmployeeName.Value, EESheet.Range("A:D"), 4, False)
            Cells(NextRow, 10) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cmbEmployeeName.Value, EESheet.Range("A:E"), 5, False)
            If EEtype = 1 Then
                Cells(NextRow, 9) = "SOH"
            Else
                Cells(NextRow, 9) = "REG"
            End If
            Cells(NextRow, 10) = Me.Controls("tbCC" & i & "RegHrs").Value

        End If

        If Me.Controls("tbCC" & i & "OTHrs").Text <> "" Then
                    NextRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
                    Cells(NextRow, 1) = tbDate.Value
                    Cells(NextRow, 2) = cmbEmployeeName.Value
                    Cells(NextRow, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cmbEmployeeName.Value, EESheet.Range("A:B"), 2, False)
                    Cells(NextRow, 4) = tbJobNumber.Value
                    Cells(NextRow, 5) = Me.Controls("tbJobExtra" & i).Value
                    Cells(NextRow, 6) = Me.Controls("cmbCC" & i).Value
                    Cells(NextRow, 7) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cmbEmployeeName.Value, EESheet.Range("A:C"), 3, False)
                    Cells(NextRow, 8) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cmbEmployeeName.Value, EESheet.Range("A:D"), 4, False)
                    Cells(NextRow, 9) = "OVT"
                    Cells(NextRow, 10) = Me.Controls("tbCC" & i & "OTHrs").Value

        End If


If i + 1 = 7 Then Exit For

If Me.Controls("cmbCC" & i + 1).Value = "" Then Exit For

Next
Bad:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "This EE Does Not Exist or You Typed Their Name Incorrectly.  Check the EE name spelling or enter the EE into the Employees Tab."
        NextRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
        Rows(NextRow).Delete
        EEpayrollentry.Hide
        Sheets("Employees").Activate
    End If

i = 1
For i = 1 To 6

    cmbEmployeeName.Value = ""
    Me.Controls("tbJobExtra" & i).Text = ""
    Me.Controls("cmbCC" & i).Text = ""
    Me.Controls("tbCC" & i & "RegHrs").Text = ""
    Me.Controls("tbCC" & i & "OTHrs").Text = ""
Next
EEpayrollentry.lbTotalHours.Caption = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: "What is the code for the Check Boxes" - your question is unclear. http://wellsr.com/vba/2015/excel/complete-guide-to-excel-vba-form-control-checkboxes/

Comment: I do not know how to connect the Check Boxes to the value in cell H1.   I know I have to write some sort of VLookup statement to pull the value in cell H1, but I also need the check boxes to enter the value into (Cells(NextRow, 4) = tbJobNumber.Value).